# How do I render this map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, gatsby, array.prototype.map

```
let array = this.props.data.allGoogleSheetSpacesRow.edges;

    const results = [...array.reduce((r, e) => {
      let k = `${e.node.twitter}`;
      if(!r.has(k)) r.set(k, {...e, count: 1})
      else r.get(k).count++
      return r;
    }, new Map)]
```

I'm using reduce to get a count of duplicate twitter usernames in my array to create a leaderboard like so:

1. Twitter Username: 5
2. Twitter Username: 4
3. Twitter Username: 2

```
let leaderboard = results;
console.log(leaderboard);

return (
        {leaderboard.map((item, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            {item.value.map((c, i) => (
              <div key={i}>
                <h3>{c.count}</h3>
                <h3>{c.node.twitter}</h3>
                <hr />
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>
        ))}

    )
```

I'm trying to map over the map to render the data but I'm not sure how to. I get `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong?

Here's a breakdown of the `map`: [image]

So the tree seems to go **array --> array --> object** but I'm not sure what I need to do to render that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, look at the docs for [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). Notice that the methods available include `entries`, `keys`, `values`, and `forEach`. There is no map method (although one could argue there should be).

Also notice that map is an iterable, so you can do a `for (let [key, value] of map){…}` (which is pretty much the same as calling `.forEach(…)` or `.entries().forEach(…)`).

What you probably want, though, is `Array.from(map.entries()).map(…)` or `[...map.entries()].map(…)`. **`.entries()`** returns a map iterator of `[key, value]` pairs, which can be converted to an array, which has a `.map(…)` method.

so your code is pretty close:

```
  return (
        <div>{Array.from(leaderboard.entries()).map(([key, value]) => (
          <div key={key}>
              <div>
                <h3>{value.count}</h3>
                <h3>{value.node.twitter}</h3>
                <hr />
              </div>
          </div>
        ))}</div>
    )
```

Comment: Any idea why I get `leaderboard.entries(...).map is not a function`?

Comment: Hm, what version of javascript/browser are you using (or what version are you transpiling to with babel)? Because it looks like you aren't getting a map as the value in results, but rather an array with the map as the first value. try `console.log(leaderboard instanceof Array)` and `console.log(leaderboard instanceof Map)`.

Comment: Also, you might want to drop the `[...`…`]` from aroundd your reduce call, if you want to keep using a map, and not convert it to an array. `[...map]` is pretty much equivalent to calling `map.entries()` in new enough versions of javascript. (Which may have been your intent...)

Comment: I'm using Gatsby's .babelrc file which I believe is same as current version of React. The clg returns `false` for instanc of Array and `true` for instanceof Map. 

When I `console.log(leaderboard.entries())` it returns ```MapIterator {"mmckvr" => {…}, "shylands" => {…}, "null" => {…}, "mccrum" => {…}, "barrymcgee" => {…}, …}
__proto__: Map Iterator
[[IteratorHasMore]]: true
[[IteratorIndex]]: 0
[[IteratorKind]]: "entries"
[[Entries]]: Array(8)
0: {"mmckvr" => Object}
...
length: 8```



No idea why its not working

Comment: Oh, hm... I thought for sure that entries was an array, but nope, it's a map iterator, and it has no `map` method. Well, `Array.from(…)` or `[...map]` should fix that...

Comment: `Array.from` did the job. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the keys of your Map:

```js
return (
        {[...leaderboard.keys()].map(key => (
          <div key={key}>
                <h3>{leaderboard.get(key).count}</h3>
                <h3>{leaderboard.get(key).node.twitter}</h3>
          </div>
        ))}
);
```

Check out this codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/o4v0695n5q

Comment: Hmm, I get `leaderboard.get() is not a function` when I try that. Any ideas why?